# Why does this following Python function definition produce a "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error when called later?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def name_space_count(name):
   if name.count(" ") == 1:
      x = name.split()
      temp = x.insert(1, "NULL")
      return temp

   else:
      x = (name.split(" "))
      return x
```

Basically, the code takes in a string for input and splits them into first, middle and last names, with the middle name in the returned list being "NULL" if there is none. However, when I try to access the first name from the resulting list further in the program (for ex. ***(name_space_count("John Mark Mulaney"))[0]*** ), I get the aforementioned error. How do I go about fixing the error ?

Comment: `list.insert` returns `None`, so you are returning `None`

Comment: @AndrejKesely why don't you put this in an answer instead? I'm new to SO, asking seriously.

Comment: @Ronald Every day there's ton of questions like this. If you want, formulate an answer and I'll upvote you.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Okay, got it. Pretty glaring mistake, in hindsight. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrejKesely yeah I'm not going to pretty much copy/paste your comment into an answer to grab some rep. :-) Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: @Ronald It's an [age old dilemma](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)